# Change top margin above page title in blogspot theme

Tags: html, margin, blogger, blogspot

Blogger.com has differences in how they display a blog post and a page.
The blog post always has the date field above, which gives a bit extra space over the post title.
On a page, the date is not displayed and the page title ends up very close to the top border of the text area.

Is there a way to change this or must I change all pages to posts?

Link to affected page: http://steinarnejensen.blogspot.no/p/birds.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Theme** > **Edit HTML** and paste this before `</head>` tag

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isPage'>
    <style>
        .post-title { margin-top: 20px; }
    </style>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thanks, Bassam. It seems that isn't making any difference. I even tried to change to value fro 20 to 90 to easier see the change. Still nothing, neither on blog post or page.  I am using the Contempo theme. Any other suggestions, please!

Comment: You need to add margin-top to the title only on pages like your example?

Comment: Thanks again for trying here and sorry for being such a newbie. However - I am not able to find any </head> tag in the HTML editor of my page text. Another issue is that the page title is not part of the page text, it is more like a file name. So I think (without having any knowledge at all!) that maybe HTML code added to the page text will not affect the page title - which is exactly what I want. :-(

Comment: I mean your xml code not page editor. from your blog control panel click Theme > Edit HTML to open your xml editor. click anywhere inside the code area, press `CTRL + F` from keyboard, and search for `</head>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and help. That worked PERFECTLY! I do not know the Stackoverflow.com system, but if there is a way to give you credit or votes for your kind help, I would like to know how!  Again: Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, Just accept my answer to help other users here.

Comment: Sorry for having to ask, but how do I accept it? I can't see any button for this. I have given you a vote (top left) is that it?

Comment: Click on the check mark beside the answer, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work